# JS refresh minimu amount

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, milliseconds

What is the minimum refresh time for a js refresh? 
What potential problems do I face with super small refreshes like every 40 millisecons... I have a good reason to do so its not madness.

```
    function refresh(){
    var refreshTime = 40;
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",refreshTime);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you refreshing the whole page? ANd not just the content that needs to be updated using JSON/AJAX/SOAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single timeout, it doesn't matter.

Instead of passing a string as a first argument, I recommend to pass a function, which allows more flexibility:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //Do anything you want
}, refreshTime);
```

For intervals (`window.setInterval()`), I usually take 50 as a minimum, because most tasks do not have to be executed over 20 times a second. Heavy functions in an INTERVAL can cause the browser to freeze (eg: multiple CSS updates -> re-rendering the page).

Comment: thanks Rob W! follow up question is there anyway to target a specific element for refresh?

Comment: @Christopher The contents of an element can be updated using `element.innerHTML = "Any<br>html";`. The HTML can be calculated dynamically, or retrieved from a server through AJAX.

Comment: yep ajax does work however i dont need to change anything externally I have a changing element on my page as the element changes i want it to invoke a change in another element. It's just an experiment but potentially a cool trick if its possible!!

Comment: Either use `.innerHTML = "newcontent";` or DOM manipulation, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild.

Answer (score 0):

This code will be probably OK.

It doesn't matter which time you insert there, I sometimes use `1`

Comment: *"This code will probably a lot of browsers and a lot of servers."*?  I don't get this.

Comment: @RobW: sorry, I missed it's in function. Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code, per se (except the string passed to `setTimeout` rather than a function).  However, refreshing a page every 40ms is not going to give the most pleasant user experience.  Page elements will flicker, clicks may sound through the speakers.

It sounds to me like you need to go for something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to keep your page updated.  This should be less stressful for the server, and smoother overall.